# Can someone correct me

Tags: javascript, list

Can someone correct this code for me:
**Missing ) after argument list.**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {           
        $(&quot;a&quot;).each(function() {
            var i = $(this).attr(&quot;href&quot;);            
            var n = i.replace(http://www.pantsumation.com, &quot;https://www.pantsumation.com&quot;);
            $(this).attr(&quot;href&quot;, function() {
                return n               
            })
        })           
    });
</script>
```

Thank you, im not that good at javascript and just starting out.

Comment: Might wanna include your code within the `<script>` tags first...

Comment: the </script> above is not included sorry.

Comment: `&quot;a&quot;` should be `"a"` and `&quot;href&quot;` should be `"href"` and `http://www.pantsumation.com, &quot;https://www.pantsumation.com&quot;` should be `"http://www.pantsumation.com", "https://www.pantsumation.com";`

Comment: i did replace already and gave me this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):417)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?attredirects=0&d=1:2)
    at init.each (jquery.min.js?attredirects=0&d=1:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):415)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to add quotes around the first URL, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function() {       
        var i = $(this).attr("href");            
        var n = i.replace("http://www.pantsumation.com", "https://www.pantsumation.com");                               
        $(this).attr("href", function() {
             return n;
        })})});
```

UPDATE

Reading what you're actually trying to do rather than the question you asked, you might find it easier to simply replace the protocol wherever it's found:

```
$("a[href]").each(function(){
    if( this.protocol === "http:")
        this.protocol = "https:"
});
```

That selector ensures you're only getting links with href's in them.  You can make a more refined selector if you don't want to get external links or similar.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: now it gave me this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):417)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?attredirects=0&d=1:2)
    at init.each (jquery.min.js?attredirects=0&d=1:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):415)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)`

Comment: do you have any `<a>` without a href? (the answer is, yes you do)

Comment: so how do i fix it?